# How do I subscribe to, follow or save questions?

Tags: support, questions, answers

I'd like to do something like "+1" or just "subscribe" to certain questions. Can't find a button for it.

By the way the next obstacle is posting itself: System says I have to wait for 40 minutes. Looks like some idiots have spammed here a lot and ruined it for noobs like me who just want to learn Blender.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange doesn't have this functionality well handled yet (notifications of other people's stuff), so here is what you can do (and what I do):

- Mark questions favorite (little star below up/down count). This adds them into list under your profile > activity > favorites. The list is public.
- Bookmark questions (or answers copying their share url) into your browser bookmarks (if you don't want others to see).
- Get an RSS reader to see new questions. The feed is: http://blender.stackexchange.com//feeds. This is like subscribing to the whole blender.stackexchange site. You can do this [for certain tags only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/is-there-a-way-to-do-rss-feeds-on-a-set-of-tags).
- To subscribe to just one question, use the question's RSS feed:

  [image]

Comment: Gosh, how could I not see that star below up/downvote? Maybe the adblocker stole it? :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Yes being brand new to SE comes with quite a few limitations. That is what the [privileges system](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) takes care of.
The 40 min wait you experienced is just for posting on the meta (it is really *quite* rare to get a brand new user asking a question here).

You will see there you need 15 rep to Up Vote anything. That takes care of the "+1" part of your question.

As [Jaroslav Jerryno Novotny](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2474/2217) pointed out there is really no good way of subscribing to a post. All we get is the favorite button (sounds very much like what you want) and the RSS feed for each post. (Personally I have never used the RSS)

When you click on the star, below the vote buttons on a question, that question gets added to your [favorites](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/54370/d-d?tab=favorites). When sorted by *activity* anything new (say an answer or an edit) will bring that post to the top of your favorites list.

Comment: Thanks. I really know why these limitations exist, I used to be a web developer / administrator in the first place. 
Also -- to my defence -- I'm above 30 so learning something new takes a bit longer than it used to ;) 

Anyway, just by asking 3 or 4 questions alltogether I got a reputation of 16 now. Yeeha.